# jQuery mobile: remember variable of page before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

One button should redirect either to page AAA or to page BBB.
This decision should depend on the choice of the buttons on the page before.

**Page 1: #home**

- Button A: links to #setpage
- Button B: links to #setpage

---

**Page 2: #setpage**

- Input: user can set something
- Button: only one button (links to page #AAA or page #BBB)

---

**Page 3: #AAA**

- User should be here, if button A clicked on Page 1

or

**Page 4: #BBB**

- User should be here, if button B clicked on Page 1

---

I think, I can do that with the localStorage of my phone/browser (I'm using jQM+PhoneGap), but is that the best solution or is there a better way?

Comment: I would handle it on the server via the user session. Just store the current page and the previous page. When you switch, the current page becomes the previous page and a new current page is written.

Comment: Hi. But I don't need the previous page. My current page should know, which button was clicked on the previous page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a single page app, you could just switch the HREF of the setpage button when clicking the A and B buttons on the home page.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sUr75/)**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#Home", function(){
    $('.btnAB').on("click", function(e){
        var id = $(this).prop("id");
        if (id === 'btnB'){
            $('#btnSetpage').prop('href', '#BBB');
        } else {
            $('#btnSetpage').prop('href', '#AAA');
        }
    });
});
```

The script above handles the click event of the 2 buttons (they have the same class).  It sees which button was clicked and then sets the href of the one button on the setpage.

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Home</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a class="btnAB" id="btnA" href="#setpage" data-role="button">A</a>
        <a class="btnAB" id="btnB" href="#setpage" data-role="button">B</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="setpage">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>setpage</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a id="btnSetpage" href="#AAA" data-role="button">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="AAA">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>AAA</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        I am AAA
        <a href="#Home" data-role="button">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="BBB">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>BBB</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        I am BBB
        <a href="#Home" data-role="button">Home</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) Do you think that's better then localStorage?

Comment: In my opinion, for a single page app this is simpler and does not require the extra browser feature (localStorage).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker)'s answer, you can retrieve all details related to the clicked button as well as *previous* and *next* pages on `pagebeforechange` event.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (event, data)
```

Those details can be obtained from *data* object. For example, clicked / linked button details are retrieved from `data.options.link` object. *previous* page `data.options.fromPage`, and *next* page `data.toPage`.

This event fires twice on transition, for the current page and the page it's moving to.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
  /* when webpage is first initialized, .link and .toPage are undefined */
  if (data.options.link && data.toPage) {
    if (data.toPage[0].id == "setpage") {
      var button = data.options.link[0].text;
      /* for demo */
      $("#setpage [data-role=content]").html("Clicked button: " + button);
    }
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uZ5AM/)**