# How to identify that current page load from which link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wonder if it is possible. I have two JQuery Mobile pages with the following structure

```
    <div data-role="page" id="main_demo">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="#main_demo1">Next</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="main_demo1">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="#main_demo">Back Using Tag</a>
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back Using Rel Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When user go to second page and press the `Buttons` on that page how to identify that user back to first page from which button either from one which has`href` attribute or other that has `data-rel` attribute

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/89Q7G/)

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this when you can do it by data-rel? You can store the page name in local storage and can move back using local storage id

Comment: why don't save the current page in a javascript variable and then check it in a back() function?

Comment: @RohitTiwari i have some requirements both thinks uses in my work

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi i want to know if i get something in `pageshow, pagebeforeshow` etc events to identify

Comment: This is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/20977698/1771795

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EzP3v/)

You can set the page name on local storage and can retrive it back in the other page button click event.

```
<div data-role="page" id="index1">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content"> <a href="#" id="Id1" data-role="button">Click Me</a>  
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content"> <a href="#" id="Id2" data-role="button">Go back</a>   
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

</div>
</div>

$('#Id1').click(function () {
  var pageid = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
  window.localStorage.setItem("pageid", pageid);
  $.mobile.changePage("#index");

});


$('#Id2').click(function () {
  var pageid = window.localStorage.getItem("pageid");
  $.mobile.changePage("#" + pageid);
});
```

Comment: Why down vote? Stackoverflow says. When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.

Comment: Does this answer  not achieve what the user wants?

Comment: I didn't down a vote. Yeah its correct and i already used that but i want to something `localStorage` because in `IOs` `localStorage` doesn't support in private mode.
Although your answer is correct