# jquery mobile send data to internal page and read from there

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to give data to a internal page of a jquery mobile app with the Get method. The app is written as a one-page solution.

If a user clicks on send I change the href of the a for example to:

```
$("#send_loc").on("click", function () {
    var shop = $("#shop").prev("form").find("input").val();
    var city = $("#city").prev("form").find("input").val();

    $('#send_loc').attr("href", "#search?city="+city+"&shop="+shop); 
});
```

On the other side I try to catch the data with:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#search", function() {
   var shop = getParameterByName("city");
   var city_name = getParameterByName("shop");

});
```

but I get no results with this.

The reason why I try to do this is, to fix the data-rel="back" button.

If a user clicks on send I generate a listview with the search parameters city and shop. But after the user clicks on a entry of the listview and goes back again to the list view the list is empty. So thats why I try to save the parameters in the URL and create the listview with the URL parameters.

thanks for any help

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974092/jquery-mobile-remember-variable-of-page-before/20977698#20977698 to retrieve the clicked link and then do whatever you want with it. If you need clarification, let me know.

Comment: Yes I'd need more clarification please. I did not really understand how to use it.

Comment: You want to retrieve value of input previous to clicked button, right?

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/g5Umg/ if this is what you want, I'll add a detailed answer.

Comment: almost. After the user searches city and shop he gets a listview of the entries which are loaded per ajax call. Then the user clicks on one of the entries and gets a page with infos to the entry. So now if the user hits the back button he goes to #search again but without any input.

Like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/g5Umg/3/

Comment: In this case, add value to back button as an attribute and retrieve it on `navigate` event along with `pagebeforechange`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-to-control-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile/18213393#18213393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an internal page I assume, that you are using single .js file. If so, there is no need in passing data. Just make a global variable (outside any functions) and store there your values.

OR

Have you considered caching your list page?

OR

Have you tried local storage? Here are some examples of using:

```
localStorage.removeItem("item");
localStorage.setItem("item", yourdata);
localStorage.getItem("item");
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: yes I tried with local storage but it does not worked. the two functions are in seperate <script> tags so I get a better overview but I can throw them together too. 

and I'm not familiar with caching in jquery. 

so to use local storage variables, they have to be in the same script?

Comment: Well I put the scripts together and used the localStorage and I get data from their too, but if I click to back after I entered a entry of the list view it still shows my a blank page. 

It seems that the code cant enter 

$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#search", function() {}); after I click on the back button

Comment: LocalStorage is independent from scipts. Try to remove data-rel="back" in your back button and instead of it add onclick event with mobile.changePage to your list's page. It should invoke pageinit event and fix your problems